# Errors: document type does not allow element "div"

Tags: validation

I have errors in my code:

```
document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag
```

And my code:

```html
<div id="head2"><a href="/" style="display: block"><div id="logo"></div></a><div id="headx"></div>
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote

```html
<div id="head2"><a href="/" style="display: block"><span id="logo" style="display: block"></span></a><div id="headx"></div>
```